# How to filter an exec log with grep?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, rclone

I run a script that moves files from my HDD to Google Drive with Rclone that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 1>> /home/user/MoveLog.txt
exec 2>&1
rclone move localfolder remotefolder:
```

Ok. So rclone shows lots of terminal activity while it is running, making the log quite large.

What I want to do is filter this output in the log created.

I wanted to have a log that looks like the output of:

```
cat MoveLog.txt | grep Copied
```

Since this command returns only the more important parts of the log.

How can I implement this on the first script, making it log only the lines that have the text "Copied" in them?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to filter the output of both, stdout and stderr and append it to the log-file:

```
rclone move localfolder remotefolder &> /dev/stdout | grep Copied >> /home/user/MoveLog.txt
```

should do what you want. I think the colon you use in your `rclone`-command doesn't belong there, so I left it out, but I might be wrong in this point.

Answer (score 3):

That seems overly complex, how about

```
#!/bin/bash
rclone move localfolder remotefolder: |& \
    tee -a "$HOME/MoveLogEntire.txt" | \
    grep "Copied" >> "$HOME/MoveLog.txt"
```

I suggest saving the whole log for diagnosis when `$HOME/MoveLog.txt` is empty.

I've changed my code to append (`tee -a`, `>>`) to the logs. I have learned to fear ever-growing files (that don't monitor available space), so I must disrecommend this solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to preserve the existing structure / style of the script, you could do something like

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 1> >(tee -a $HOME/MoveLog.txt | grep 'Copied' >> $HOME/CopiedLog.txt)
exec 2>&1
```

This redirects `stdout` (file descriptor #1) to a *process substitution*, where we  first append it to the primary log file `$HOME/MoveLog.txt`, then filter the `tee`d stream with grep and append that to a secondary log `$HOME/CopiedLog.txt`

Since this is a bash script, you could replace the first `1>` by `&>` and omit the separate `exec 2>&1` redirection.